# Hide class if date is greater than or equal to 08/01/2023 and time is past 2:00pm PST using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to hide the class ".test" if it is past 2:00pm PST on 8/11/2023

```
 const date = new Date();
  var timeout = Fri Jun 17 2022 11:27:28 PST+0100;
  if (date >= timeout) {
     $('.text').hide();
  }
```

Comment: Consider a string for your date then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: You have two timezones in your date. `PST` and `+0100`. Which is correct?

Comment: @Barmar  I would image it's -0700,  PST + 1hr.

Answer (score 0):

`timeout` needs to be a `Date` object.

```
var timeout = new Date('2022-06-17 11:27:28-0700')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not match your code i.e. "if it is past 2:00pm PST on 8/11/2023" since today is 8/1/2023 not 8/11.

But, let's assume you get the proper date then it is a matter of comparing two dates (as numbers since the epoch ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Get the date parsed properly then you can use the values.  Here I use both the `.hide()` and the  `.toggle(bool)` from jQuery  - so with `.toggle` we can even avoid the conditional wrap and just hide it with a "false" value. ref: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display

```js
const nowdate = Date.now(); // make this a number to be consistent
const timeout = 'Fri Jun 17 2022 11:27:28 PST+0100';
let myTime = Date.parse(timeout);
console.log('It is a number:', myTime);
const optionsME = {
  timeZone: 'PST'
};
console.log(nowdate, nowdate, myTime, nowdate >= myTime, nowdate - myTime);
console.log(new Date(nowdate).toLocaleString(undefined, optionsME));
console.log(new Date(myTime).toLocaleString(undefined, optionsME));
//use < to make simple bool false to toggle:
$('.toggle-test').toggle(nowdate < myTime);

if (nowdate >= myTime) {
  console.log(nowdate, myTime, nowdate >= myTime, myTime - nowdate);
  $('.text-test').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="text-test">tester out</div>
<div class="toggle-test">toggler out</div>
```